# Please help me get the ratio of x to y

Tags: equation-solving, summation, sequence

I need the ratio of x to y in this equation:

```
sum [n*(x/10)^n/10^(n-2)] == y from n=1 to ∞
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is this about `Mathamatica` the software, or is it about math? Should we then forward the question to [math.se]?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe?

```
Solve[Sum[n (x/10)^n/10^(n-2),{n,1,\[Infinity]}]==y/.x->a y,a]/.a->x/y
```

> {{x/y->(100 (50+y-10 Sqrt[25+y]))/y^2},{x/y->(100 (50+y+10 Sqrt[25+y]))/y^2}}

Answer (score 0):

```
x/Sum[n (x/10)^n/10^(n - 2), {n, \[Infinity]}]
```

> ```
> (-100 + x)^2/10000
> ```